# editable JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have editable `JComboBox` and wish to add values to it from its input,e.s when I typing something in `JComboBox` and press enter I want that text appear in `JComboBox` list :

```
public class Program extends JFrame 
    implements ActionListener {
    private JComboBox box;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Program().setVisible(true);
    }

    public Program() {
        super("Text DEMO");
        setSize(300, 300);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        Container cont = getContentPane();
        box = new JComboBox(new String[] { "First", "Second", "..." });
        box.setEditable(true);
        box.addActionListener(this);
        cont.add(box);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        box.removeActionListener(this);
        box.insertItemAt(box.getSelectedItem(), 0);
        box.addActionListener(this);
    }
}
```

unfortunately when I press enter two values were inserted instead of one.

Why?

Comment: I amended your post, please revert if...

Answer (score 16):

From the [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#addActionListener%28java.awt.event.ActionListener%29) for `JComboBox` :

> The ActionListener will receive an ActionEvent when a selection has been made. If the combo box is editable, then an ActionEvent will be fired when editing has stopped.

Thus, your `ActionListener` is called two times.

To only add the item to the `JComboBox` when edited, you can check for the correct `ActionCommand` like this :

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("comboBoxEdited")) {
    //code
    }
}
```

**edit ( -> event dispatch thread)**

As already mentioned by [trashgod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/230513/trashgod), you should also create and show your frame only in the event dispatch thread :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Program().setVisible(true); 
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: +1 Also start on [the event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: with for output from JComboBox to the outside f.e. to the GUI is better look for ItemListener, from output from JComboBox to itself is required Action +1

Comment: Just a quick question: Is the actionCommand "comboBoxEdited" shouted to the listener automatically, or do I need to addActionCommand somehow?