# Adding new Items to ComboBox in Runtime

Tags: java, jcombobox

Its maybe a pretty simple question but i stuck there anyway.

You can set an JComboBox to Editable to insert Values. Normaly theire used for filtering the list.

What i want is that wenn the User enter a Value an exit the field, the programm should check wether the Value is already in the List and if not. It should add it to the list.

I would add a Code Snipped. But at the moment i only got the declaration for the ComboBox.

Comment: Use a model for combobox and add the model to the combobox. Add items to the model statically or dynamically. The items will get displayed in the combobox. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html

Comment: @Jayaprasad: The main Problem is that i dont know how to read out the Textfield of the Combobox.

Comment: possible duplicate of [editable JComboBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395164/editable-jcombobox)

Comment: combo.getEditor().getItem();

Comment: may be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10072335/get-input-values-from-jcombobox

Comment: @Nivas: Jep it its... I searched but didnt found it. Thanks

Comment: @Jayaprasad: Worked. Thanks and yes it is... I'm just to dumb to search...